# image view frame in cell of a table view

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uitableview

I've added an image to the resources folder of my iOS app. I want to add that image to each cell of my `UITableView`. I adjust the size of image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 27, 30, 30);
}
```

But my image displays at a size like a resources file image, but I want it at a frame mentioned above.

My research gives me this idea:

```
-(void)layoutsubviews
{
   cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 27, 30, 30);
}
```

How do I use this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
-(void)layoutsubviews
    {
       self.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 27, 30, 30);
    }
```

I am not sure how the compiler is letting you access the `cell` in the `-layoutSubviews` method. In short, whatever frames you set here will override the default frames of a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeAspectFit];`?

Comment: just call that line of code right before you set the image. you shouldn't have to know how 'layoutsubviews' works to accomplish what you are talking about

Comment: sorry i just gone through research and i found it.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeAspectFit];
     [cell.imageView setImage:yourImage];
        }